# IEnumerator: Is it normal to have an empty Dispose method?

Tags: .net, idisposable, ienumerator

I'm writing an [`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx) class to iterate over a [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) collection I'm [wrappering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).  I've noticed that `IEnumerator<T>` extends [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), so I'm required to implement the `Dispose` method.

However, I can't think of anything I would put there, as I only have a reference to the collection (which I wouldn't want being disposed at the end of a `foreach`), and an `int` for the index.  Is it normal to leave the `Dispose` method empty?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it is.

`IEnumerator<T>` implements `IDisposable` in case you make an enumerator that does need to be disposed.  Since most enumerators don't need to be disposed, the method will usually be empty.

By the way, you can implement your `IEnumerator` more easily by [creating an iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators#enumeration-sources-with-iterator-methods).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about `yield`.  I thought there was an easier way.

Comment: By the way, `yield` is one of the reasons that `IEnumerator<T>` implements `IDisposable` - a `using` statement or `finally` block goes in `Dispose`.

Comment: For VB.NET users, note that `Yield` requires Visual Studio 2012 or higher.

Comment: "`IEnumerator<T>` implements `IDisposable` in case you make an enumerator that does need to be disposed" this makes no sense. Why can't I specify `IDisposable` myself when I actually need it?

Comment: @Pawcio: Because then callsites that use it via the interface won't know to dispose it.

Comment: What "callsites"? Don't get this... Can't you check if an enumerator is `IDisposable` with `is` or `as` operator?