# How to iterate through two collections of the same length using a single foreach

Tags: c#

I know this question has been asked many times before but I tried out the answers and they don't seem to work.

I have two lists of the same length but not the same type, and I want to iterate through both of them at the same time as `list1[i]` is connected to `list2[i]`.

Eg:

Assuming that i have list1 (as `List<string>`) and list2 (as `List<int>`)

I want to do something like

```
foreach( var listitem1, listitem2 in list1, list2)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What about having a foreach for the second list inside the first foreach?

Comment: Dupe:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630758/how-to-loop-through-two-lists-simultaneously

Comment: @Jonathan - VB.NET is not C# - not a duplicate.

Comment: @Oded: My Fault. I'm working with both at the same time right now and sometimes my mind can't even see the difference.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Edit - Iterating whilst positioning at the same index in both collections**

If the requirement is to move through both collections in a 'synchronized' fashion, i.e. to use the 1st element of the first collection with the 1st element of the second collection, then 2nd with 2nd, and so on, without needing to perform any side effecting code, then see [@sll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8518803/314291) and use `.Zip()` to project out pairs of elements at the same index, until one of the collections runs out of elements.

**More Generally**

Instead of the `foreach`, you can access the `IEnumerator` from the `IEnumerable` of both collections using the `GetEnumerator()` method and then call `MoveNext()` on the collection when you need to move on to the next element in that collection. This technique is common when processing two or more ordered streams, without needing to materialize the streams.

```
var stream1Enumerator = stream1.GetEnumerator();
var stream2Enumerator = stream2.GetEnumerator();
var currentGroupId = -1; // Initial value
// i.e. Until stream1Enumerator runs out of 
while (stream1Enumerator.MoveNext())
{
   // Now you can iterate the collections independently
   if (stream1Enumerator.Current.Id != currentGroupId)
   {
       stream2Enumerator.MoveNext();
       currentGroupId = stream2Enumerator.Current.Id;
   }
   // Do something with stream1Enumerator.Current and stream2Enumerator.Current
}
```

As others have pointed out, if the collections are materialized and support indexing, such as an `ICollection` interface, you can also use the subscript `[]` operator, although this feels rather clumsy nowadays:

```
var smallestUpperBound = Math.Min(collection1.Count, collection2.Count);
for (var index = 0; index < smallestUpperBound; index++)
{
     // Do something with collection1[index] and collection2[index]
}
```

Finally, there is also an [overload of Linq's `.Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which provides the index ordinal of the element returned, which could also be useful.

e.g. the below will pair up all elements of `collection1` alternatively with the first two elements of `collection2`:

```
var alternatePairs = collection1.Select(
    (item1, index1) => new 
    {
        Item1 = item1,
        Item2 = collection2[index1 % 2]
    });
```

Comment: Don't forget to `Dispose()` (or wrap in `using`) the enumerators.

Comment: Y, good point, although most in memory collection iterator Dispose implementations [will be a no-op](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3061628/)

Answer (score 53):

This is possible using .NET 4 LINQ [Zip() operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) or using open source [MoreLINQ library](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) which provides `Zip()` operator as well so you can use it in more earlier .NET versions

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };

// The following example concatenates corresponding elements of the
// two input sequences.
var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (first, second) => first + " " + second);
foreach (var item in numbersAndWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

// OUTPUT:
// 1 one
// 2 two
// 3 three
```

Useful links:

- Soure code of the MoreLINQ Zip() implementation: [MoreLINQ Zip.cs](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Zip.cs?r=162)

Comment: http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/11/03/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-3-intermezzo-linq-s-new-zip-operator.aspx

Comment: That's all well and good if the OP was asking about something specific such as concatentation, but not all use cases are going to benefit from this.

Answer (score 16):

Short answer is no you can't.

Longer answer is that is because `foreach` is syntactic sugar - it gets an iterator from the collection and calls `Next` on it. This is not possible with *two* collections at the same time.

If you just want to have a single loop, you can use a `for` loop and use the same index value for both collections.

```
for(int i = 0; i < collectionsLength; i++)
{
   list1[i];
   list2[i];
}
```

An alternative is to merge both collections into one using the LINQ [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) operator (new to .NET 4.0) and iterate over the result.

Answer (score 12):

```
foreach(var tup in list1.Zip(list2, (i1, i2) => Tuple.Create(i1, i2)))
{
  var listItem1 = tup.Item1;
  var listItem2 = tup.Item2;
  /* The "do stuff" from your question goes here */
}
```

It can though be such that much of your "do stuff" can go in the lambda that here creates a tuple, which would be even better.

If the collections are such that they can be iterated, then a `for()` loop is probably simpler still though.

Update: Now with the built-in support for `ValueTuple` in C#7.0 we can use:

```
foreach ((var listitem1, var listitem2) in list1.Zip(list2, (i1, i2) => (i1, i2)))
{
    /* The "do stuff" from your question goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the two IEnumerable<> in helper class:

```
var nums = new []{1, 2, 3};
var strings = new []{"a", "b", "c"};

ForEach(nums, strings).Do((n, s) =>
{
  Console.WriteLine(n + " " + s);
});

//-----------------------------

public static TwoForEach<A, B> ForEach<A, B>(IEnumerable<A> a, IEnumerable<B> b)
{
  return new TwoForEach<A, B>(a, b);   
}

public class TwoForEach<A, B>
{
  private IEnumerator<A> a;
  private IEnumerator<B> b;

  public TwoForEach(IEnumerable<A> a, IEnumerable<B> b)
  {
    this.a = a.GetEnumerator();
    this.b = b.GetEnumerator();
  }

  public void Do(Action<A, B> action)
  {
    while (a.MoveNext() && b.MoveNext())
    {
      action.Invoke(a.Current, b.Current);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a foreach, why not use a for()?  for example...

```
int length = list1.length;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    // do stuff with list1[i] and list2[i] here.
}
```