# Inside the foreach loop how to get array values with out using index/count

Tags: asp.net

```
public void strgetting(string sparam = "@occ1,@occ2,@occ3", string value = "val1,val2,val3")
        {
            string[] result = sparam.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);           
            foreach (string result2 in  value.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None))
            {
                int i = 0;
                string result3 = result[i]; i++;
              Response.Write(result3 + '=' + result2 + ",<br>");
            }
        }
        OUTPUT:@occ1=val1,
               @occ2=val2,
               @occ3=val3,
```

Comment: Checkout out question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518761/how-to-iterate-through-two-collections-of-the-same-length-using-a-single-foreach
I believe the 2nd or 4th answer will lead you to your answer.

Comment: yes, i got it...thnk u public void strgetting(string sparam = "@occ1,@occ2,@occ3", string value = "val1,val2,val3")
        {
         
                  var numbersAndWords = sparam.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None).Zip(value.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None), (first, second) => first + " = " + second + ",<br>");
                 foreach (var item in numbersAndWords)
                   {
                    Response.Write(item);
                   }
           
        }