# Relation between IEnumerator<T>.Current and IEnumerator.Current and Why IEnumerator<T> implements IDisposable

Tags: .net, generics, collections

I am implementing ICollection< T > and there are problems doing enumerator implementation.

I understand that IEnumerator< T > has to implement IEnumerator for back-compatibility (.NET 1.0)

But If i am implementing IEnumerator< T >, then there are 2 Current Properties.

I have 2 questions:

1. What should be their relation ? Is following code correct ?

   ```
   T IEnumerator<T>.Current 
   { 
       get 
       {
           if (_cursor < 0 || _cursor >= _array.Length)
               throw new InvalidOperationException("Iterator position invalid");
           else 
               return _array[_cursor];
       } 
   }


   object IEnumerator.Current
   {
       get
       {
           return IEnumerator<T>.Current;
       }
   }
   ```

I get this error:  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator.Current.get'

(2). Why IEnumerator< T > has to implement IDisposable. Dispose is for unmanaged resources, but in what scenario in-general would Enumerator use unmanaged resources ?

Comment: The second question is a duplicate of this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232558/why-ienumerator-of-t-inherts-from-idisposable-but-non-generic-ienumerator-does-n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several cases where it's useful that `IEnumerator<T>` inherits from `IDisposable`.

For example take `File.ReadLines()` which needs to keep open a `FileStream`, which is an unmanaged resource.

Or if you think about an iterator using the `yield syntax` you need `IDisposable` to make finally clauses work correctly:

```
IEnumerator<int> MyIt()
{
  try
  {
    yield return 1;
  }
  finally
  {
    //Do Something
  }
}
```

Typically you'd implement `Current` like this:

```
T Current//Implicit interface implementation
{
  get
  {
    return something;
  }
}

object IEnumerator.Current{get{return Current;}}
```

Your original code doesn't work since you try to get a static property on the interface itself. You probably wanted to to `((IEnumerator<T>)this).Current`. But if you implement `T Current{...}` implicitly you don't need that cast at all.

Comment: I did    object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                return (IEnumerator<T>)this.Current;
            }
        }     but it has compile error again saying definition of Current could not be found.

Comment: `.` has higher precedence than casting. Notice the extra parentheses in my code.

Comment: works now. 1 question on Dispose. Compiler needs Dispose to be public Dispose, why ? Interface methods need not have any access modifier , right ? For MoveNext, Reset I had to remove public because complier complained so.

Comment: If you make it a normal method that implicitly implements an interface you need to make it public. If you're implementing an interface explicitly you can't specify a visibility manually, since the interface already determines the visibility.

Answer (score 1):

1. `return ((IEnumerator<T>)this).Current;`
2. `Dispose()` is used to tell enumerator that it is not needed anymore (so you can, for example, disconnect from some data source, or do something else).