# What kind of class does yield return return

Tags: c#

So I've notice that this code works:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Int32[ ]numbers = {1,2,3,4,5};

        using (var enumerator = Data().GetEnumerator())
        {

        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<String> Data()
    {
        yield return "Something";
    }
}
```

In particular, I'm curious about the `using` block, since:

```
Int32[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

using (var enumerator = numbers.GetEnumerator())
{

}
```

fails with a compiler error. Obviously, the class that `yield return` returns is `IDisposable` while a regular array enumerator is not. So now I'm curious: what exactly does `yield return` create?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why IEnumerator of T inherts from IDisposable, but non-generic IEnumerator does NOT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232558/why-ienumerator-of-t-inherts-from-idisposable-but-non-generic-ienumerator-does)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`IEnumerator<T>` implements `IDisposable`, as you can see in the Object Browser or in MSDN.

The non-generic `IEnumerator` does not.

The base `Array` class implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>`.  (since `Array` is not generic)
Concrete array types do implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but they implement `GetEnumerator()` explicitly (I'm not sure why).
Therefore, the `GetEnumerator()` visible on any array type returns `IEnumerator`.

The generic `IEnumerable<T>` implementation returns a `System.SZArrayHelper.SZGenericArrayEnumerator<T>`.

The source code for this class (in `Array.cs`) has the following comment which partially explains this (remember, all support for generic arrays dates back to a time when `IEnumerable<T>` was not contraviant)

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
// ! READ THIS BEFORE YOU WORK ON THIS CLASS. 
//
// The methods on this class must be written VERY carefully to avoid introducing security holes. 
// That's because they are invoked with special "this"! The "this" object
// for all of these methods are not SZArrayHelper objects. Rather, they are of type U[]
// where U[] is castable to T[]. No actual SZArrayHelper object is ever instantiated. Thus, you will
// see a lot of expressions that cast "this" "T[]". 
//
// This class is needed to allow an SZ array of type T[] to expose IList<T>, 
// IList<T.BaseType>, etc., etc. all the way up to IList<Object>. When the following call is 
// made:
// 
//   ((IList<T>) (new U[n])).SomeIListMethod()
//
// the interface stub dispatcher treats this as a special case, loads up SZArrayHelper,
// finds the corresponding generic method (matched simply by method name), instantiates 
// it for type <T> and executes it.
// 
// The "T" will reflect the interface used to invoke the method. The actual runtime "this" will be 
// array that is castable to "T[]" (i.e. for primitivs and valuetypes, it will be exactly
// "T[]" - for orefs, it may be a "U[]" where U derives from T.) 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: While we are at it, I haven't seen any code that uses a `using` block as shown by OP. Is this necessary, considering that it is mere looping on the items than using an OS resource such as connection, file, bitmap etc.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: `foreach` will call `Dispose()` in a `finally` block if the enumerator implements `IDisposable`.  If you call `GetEnumerator()` yourself, it's your responsibility to dispose it.  `IDisposable` is not only for unmanaged resources; it's for anything that needs deterministic cleanup.   Also, what about `Directory.EnumerateFiles()`?

Comment: The reason that array types implement `IEnumerable` implicitly and `IEnumerable<T>` explicitly is backwards compatibility.  There was a non-generic `GetEnumerator` instance method, and they couldn't take it away without it being a (more significant) breaking change.  The majority of the other collections used were all added in or after .NET 2.0, so `IEnumerable<T>` existed when they were first created, and that could be the implicitly implemented interface.  Any collection existing before then most likely doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` implicitly (then again, most can't at all...)

Comment: @Servy: Are you sure that changing `GetEnumerator()` to return a type that implements its previous return type is a breaking change?  I suspect that this is mostly due to the variance issue.  (arrays implement more than one `IEnumerable<T>`)

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks for your reply. I think you'll agree that `Dispose` is needed to do cleanup of OS resource used (which needs deterministic cleanup than to wait for GC to do it). In that sense, `foreach` is a better way to deal with `Directory.EnumerateFiles` than using `for(;;)` or `GetNumerator`. Is that fair to assume?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: No. `Dispose()` can be needed for other things too (eg, to release a read lock, or for reference counting).  And, `foreach()` is not the only way to consume an `IEnumerator` (many LINQ methods don't use it, for example).  As long as you make sure to dispose it (typically using `using`), you're fine.