# Mystery behind System.Array

Tags: c#, .net

We know `System.Array` is a abstract class and whatever `DataType[]` we use runtime creates some concrete implementation for us somehow (vague though).

Consider the following snippet.

```
int[] someInts = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
IList<int> collection = someInts;
collection.Clear();
```

`collection.Clear()` throws `NotSupportedException`, Nothing surprising there. When I check to see the "StackTrace" am surprised to see it shows some strange "Type" `SZArrayHelper` at top of the call stack.

StackTrace:

```
   at System.SZArrayHelper.Clear[T]()//Note this.. How???
   at TestApplication.Program.Main()
```

How come that is possible? am calling `Clear()` method on `int[]` but then how does the call go to `SZArrayHelper.Clear`. note that `Clear` is an instance method in `SZArrayHelper` defined as below.

```
private void Clear<T>()
{
    throw new NotSupportedException(Environment.GetResourceString("NotSupported_ReadOnlyCollection"));
}
```

Who creates the instance of "SZArrayHelper" and also note that Clear method is *private*. Am very confused about what's happening. If at all an instance of "SZArrayHelper" is created and `Clear` is called then that helper method doing this call should come in  the "StackTrace". But that is not the case here.

Can somebody explain what's happening behind the scenes?

Note:

1. `int[]` is just an example, you can pretty much simulate it with any type of array, and not only `Clear` method `Add`, `Contains` etc possesses same behavior.
2. I tried to debug using reflector addin, which gave me the same results. The debugger shows a direct call to `SZArrayHelper.Clear<T>()`.
3. Google led me to this [.NET Arrays, IList, Generic Algorithms, and what about STL?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2004/11/19/267089.aspx). That helped to understand the kind of magic that is going on behind the scenes, but some mystery still remains.

Comment: Am not sure whether c# tag is relevant. I just added it since I tried it with c# and many folks would be monitoring it.

Comment: Private class methods can implement public interface methods.

Comment: @rninty My question is not that. and private class can implement interfaces but methods can't be private. That is not the case here

Comment: This has always annoyed me that the array type implements `IList<T>` - since it can't do the basic stuff that a list can, like adding items, removing items, clearing itself, etc. I'm sure there's a reason it was done that way, but it's caught me a few times.

Comment: @JoeEnos - Object of `IList<T>` should be expected to behave this way when it returns `IsReadOnly=true` (like arrays - `((IList<int>)(new int[3])).IsReadOnly == true` ).

Comment: `Array` implement `IList<T>` at runtime. Apparently this implemenation calls `SZArrayHelper.Clear<T>()`

Comment: @Magnus If so, where is the method that calls `SZArrayHelper.Clear<T>()` in stacktrace? That is missing.

Comment: Arrays are basically voodoo. Because they pre-date generics, yet must allow on-the-fly type-creation (even in .NET 1.0), they are implemented using tricks, hacks, and sleight of hand. I *think* what you are seeing is basically the implementation details of the trickery. It is all very interesting, but sometimes it is best to stay outside the curtain and enjoy the show. Ignorance is bliss ;p

Comment: @JoeEnos I agree. This is just one of many dreadful abuses of the Liskov Substitution Principle - that lies at the heart of all good SOLID designs- the MS is guilty of. There must be a reason it was done this way, but I can't think of a *good* reason. There again MS have committed the same sins with the new immutable collections classes and the excuse there was nothing more than bowing pressure from developers who didn't know what they were talking about sadly.

Comment: @DavidArno I'd be interested in more details on these "same sins". This probably isn't the right place, though.

Comment: @MarcGravell you're right. on the other hand if somebody can answer me then I'd learn something new. Am curious and confused too. :)

Comment: The [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15341925/468973) for the array class might help to shed some light on the subject.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm talking of things like ReadOnlyCollection implementing IList and throwing a not implemented exception when eg Clear() is called, rather than having IList<> extend IReadOnlyList<> and have ReadOnlyCollection<> implement the latter only. That would have been employing the SOLID principle.

Comment: @DavidArno That would mean all lists would be `IReadOnlyList<>`. Not sure I like that.

Comment: @Magnus Not so. It would simply mean all lists would implement the IReadOnlyList contract and even a mutable list could be supplied to a method that required a IReadOnlyList instance. In reality, I personally would have made IList<> an immutable contract and extended it via a IMutableList<> interface. But that's largely semantics. The Liskov substitution principle would be upheld either way.

Comment: @DavidArno They would all _implement_ `IReadOnlyList<>` which does not feel right. But I see your point.

Comment: @DavidArno without supporting the legacy interfaces, they would be of limited use; too much code is read-only by for historic reasons uses `IList[<T>]`. Fortunately, there is `IList.ReadOnly` which code *can check*

Comment: @MarcGravell It was those legacy interfaces that I was criticising. Liskov formulated the idea in '87, long before .NET was conceived, thus there is no real excuse for those botched interfaces.

Comment: Related:  ["Arrays and the CLR - a Very Special Relationship"](http://mattwarren.org/2017/05/08/Arrays-and-the-CLR-a-Very-Special-Relationship/) links back to this question, specifically @MarcGravell's comment about array voodoo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not seeing any call to that method, because you're invoking it yourself, as weird as that may sound. `SZArrayHelper` is a CLR wrapper around an array, that implements the `IList<T>` interface, kinda like the adapter pattern.

From this perspective, it makes sense that `collection.Clear` invokes `SZArrayHelper.Clear` directly.

Hans Passant explains this very well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11164210/857807

Comment: I support this answer :)

Comment: @HansPassant I suppose you know every corner of CLR, Great.. Thank you very much.. After you support this answer I have no way other than accepting this answer :)

Comment: @dcastro Thank you very much. valuable link. That clears it up.

Comment: I am nothing but a humble disciple ^^